# Problem with Java Timestamp with SQL Date type

Tags: java, spring-boot, sql-timestamp

In my db table I have a column `c_dob` of Type `date`

For my controller Request class, I use the above field like this :

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
public class UpdateUserProfileRequest {

    private Timestamp dob;
    public Timestamp getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(Timestamp dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
}
```

Problems :

- What happens is when I have the value `1979-06-30` passed as a
  request json value, in the controller class, the request class logs
  the value as `1979-06-30 02:00:00.0` (hour part is added and given a value on its own)
- Second, for setting the dob the following code I am using :

  ```
  Map<String, Object> outMap = proc.execute(inParams);       
  profile.setDob((Date) outMap.get("out_dob") != null
                           ? new Timestamp(((Date) outMap.get("out_dob")).getTime()) : null);
  ```

And what happens here is that `1979-06-30 02:00:00.0` is changed to `1979-06-30 01:00:00.0` which causes logical problem.

So, is there any reason or any solution for this behavior?

Edit  : Database is MySql

Comment: What database? And are you sure the data type is named exactly `DATE`?

Comment: FYI, the class `java.sql.Timestamp` is terribly flawed, and was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque Database is mysql

Comment: @BasilBourque Java.sql.time represents only the time part and not the date part.

Comment: No, `java.sql.Time` is also one of the terrible legacy classes. You need to learn about the classes in the *java.time* package, defined in JSR 310. Search Stack Overflow to learn more. There are many hundreds of existing Questions and Answers.

Comment: Don't use the `javax.sql` classes in your model. Instead use the newer `java.time` ones. Also `Timestamp` is both a data **and** time hence the time will be added. If you really want to stick with the javax.sql stuff (which I hardly recommend) use `Date` which is only a data without time.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong data types. The MySQL type `DATE` represents a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone. In contrast, the `java.sql.Timestamp` class represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline, a date with time-of-day as seen in UTC. Square peg, round hole.

Use only *java.time* classes. Never use the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `Timestamp`.

For MySQL `DATE` use `java.time.LocalDate` with a JDBC driver that complies with JDBC 4.2 or later.

```
LocalDate localDate = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `java.time.LocalDateTime` which is timezone aware and should help you a lot...

java.sql.Timestamp is a terrible and some leftover of the dark ages :)

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. *java.sql.Timestamp is a terrible …* Correct. *`java.time.LocalDateTime` which is timezone aware …* Incorrect. *… and should help you a lot...* It’s far better to use `LocalDate` for a date without time of day.